# jquery dynamic dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#website').change(function() {

    $.get('inc/dropdown.php',{id: $(this).val() },function(d){
        $('#loc').replaceWith(d);
    });
});
});
```

With this HTML on the first drop down list.

```
<label for="website"><strong>Web Site:</strong></label>
<?php inc dynamic form ?>
```

and this  that gets replaced with the dynamic drop down.

```
 <span id="loc">Please select an option from above.</span>
```

The issue I am having is that when I click between the items in the Web Site dropdown it doesn't update the other dropdown. It sticks on the first that it was clicked on.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/jMhPx/2 - the jsfiddle you supplied. I'd be interested to know what data is getting passed. Could you `console.log` the `d` and see what you are getting? Also, could you explain what you mean by "other dropdown" and what you mean by getting stuck on the first?

Comment: When you click one of the entries on the list it sends a ID to a PHP file. This then creates another drop down box that is echoed out which gets displayed. What happens is when you click on one it works as it should but if you click another drop down entry it just sits with the old drop down. The location drop down is the the one thats dyanmically made depending on what value is selected in the website drop down. @smerny

Comment: What is contained in `d`? If it doesn't contain `#loc`, the reason it wont work the second time is because `#loc` doesn't exist anymore (you are replacing it)

Comment: DOH! that make total sense! Tweaked the code and it works now. thanks for pointing out that major error! Jquery and Javascript aren't my strong points!

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I am having is that when I click between the items in the Web Site dropdown it doesn't update the other dropdown

What do you mean by other dropdown? Here you are using IDs so you can't have other dropdowns using same script. If you need this code to be usable by different elements you should consider using a class instead.

Also, you are using `.replaceWith` instead of `.text`, `.replaceWith` should be used when replacing DOM elements, is that your intention?